# Two Tableviews in one Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

So I'm trying to make two tableviews in one view and I'm having some trouble.
I've read some other response on how to do it but they don't exactly help me.

In my .h file I made two outlets for two views calling them `myFirstViewText` and `mySecondViewTex`

So in my m files for - `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{`

I want to be able to print out seperate values in each different controller and I'm not too sure since you only return 1 cell?

So far i've Done this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Rx";
static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"allergies";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
UITableViewCell *cell2 = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
if(!cell){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
if (!cell2) {
    cell2 = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
}
if (tableView == self.myFirstTextView ) {
       cell.textLabel.text = @"HI JAZZY";//[RxDict objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
if (tableView == self.mySecondTextView) {
      cell.textLabel.text = @"BYE JAZZY";//[RxDict objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
tableView = self.mySecondTextView;
cell2.textLabel.text = @"I love Jazzy :D";
return cell2;
```

This prints "I love Jazzy" in my first TableView and nothing gets printed in the second one. Why does this happen and how can I fix it?
Thanks :D

Answer (score 7):

This method gets called by all tableViews that have an instance of your class set as their dataSource.

This means you need to check *which* tableView was asking for cell number so-and-so.

So, your method should basically look like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == rxTableView) {
        //prepare and return the appropriate cell for *this* tableView
    }
    else if (tableView == allergiesTableView) {
        //prepare and return the appropriate cell for *this* tableView
    }
    return nil; //because you don't expect any other tableView to call this method
}
```

Comment: Note that returning nil will cause your program to crash...  You are better off returning a blank cell or alerting the user to an unrecoverable error, and having them restart the app.

Comment: @lnafziger You're right that this will cause the app to crash. I think this is a good thing. You don't expect any TableViews you don't know to ask for data, and you couldn't provide it anyway. Crashing as early as possible is good, if something can't be statically checked as is the case here. Anyway, it's beside the point - it shouldn't matter what's returned there, as that line should never be reached.

Comment: Actually, in my opinion, crashing is bad when you can provide a controlled shut down.  But it is still worth pointing out to those that don't know when you include it in your code.  :)

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion would be to set a tag on both of your table views and then in your tableview dataSource methods check for which the tag the table view your are in. So for instance some where in your code you can do:

```
myFirstTableView.tag = 1;
mySecondTableView.tag = 2;
```

later when your are in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if (tableView.tag == 1) 
   cell.textLabel.text = @"HI JAZZY";//[RxDict objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   if (tableView.tag == 2) 
   cell.textLabel.text = @"BYE JAZZY";
 }
```

Also if you have 2 tableviews with different sizes you can achieve this like this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {
    if (tableView.tag == 1)
         return 1;
    else if (tableView.tag == 2)
         return 2;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach I don't see implemented too often is actually to use a NSObject subclass to act as the delegate and datasource for each table, not the view controller.  It removes the need for the "if (tableView == someTable) ..." code, and might make both your view controller and UITableView code maintainable and readable.

You'd create an NSObject subclass for each table.  These subclasses would contain the desired implementation of your UITableView datasource and delegate methods.  You'd then instantiate one of each in your view controller and hook each up to its appropriate table.

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1:

```
tableView = self.mySecondTextView;     
cell2.textLabel.text = @"I love Jazzy :D";
return cell2;
```

What you are doing here is always returning `cell2`, setting its text "I love jazzy :D" so it will always fill the first table view because you would not have set the `tableView=mySecondTextView` before entering into the method. The delegate is always targeting `firstTableView`.

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Problem 2:

```
if (tableView == self.myFirstTextView ) {
    cell.textLabel.text = @"HI JAZZY";
    //[RxDict objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //for printing in first table view return cell here like

    return cell;
}
if (tableView == self.mySecondTextView) {
    cell.textLabel.text = @"BYE JAZZY";
    //[RxDict objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //for printing in second tableview return cell two here

    return cell2;
}
```

Make sure the table you want to target is set before entering into this function. You can set it in `numberofsection` method, the view `didload` method or somewhere else from where you want to show or target table view (like clicking on some button). But you can't set it here.